# Center align a JavaScript script on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
        <style>
          #titlePic {
            text-align: center;
          }
          #3dCanvas {
            text-align: center;
          }
          #difficulties {
            text-align: center;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id='titlePic'>
            <h1>
                <img src="../IndividualProject/images/SHIFT_PROMO.png" alt="SHIFT_PROMO" width="512" height="250"/>
            </h1>
            </div>
        <div id='3dCanvas'>
                <script src='./Scripts/three.min.js'></script>
                <script src='./Scripts/threex.text.js'></script>
                <script src="./Scripts/droid_serif_bold.typeface.js"></script>
                <script src='./Scripts/3dText.js'></script>
                </div>
            <div id='difficulties'>
                <h2>
                <a href="index.html"><img src="../IndividualProject/images/Marathon.png" alt="Marathon" width="321" height="54" /></a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="index.html"><img src="../IndividualProject/images/Easy.png" alt="Easy" width="164" height="48" /></a>
                <br><br>    
                <a href="index.html"><img src="../IndividualProject/images/Medium.png" alt="Medium" width="225" height="48" /></a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="index.html"><img src="../IndividualProject/images/Hard.png" alt="Hard" width="162" height="48" /></a>
                <br><br>
                </h2>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Im trying to move this 3D animated text to the center of the HTML page but nothing seems to work, any help?

The JavaScript files are located in 3dCanvas, text align seems to do nothing

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNVwop here is a codepen

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle or something?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNVwop here is a codepen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just

`body { text-align: center; }`

or

`canvas { margin: 0 auto; display: block;}`

I didn't figured out who does create canvas: it seems it will be better to edit that script to make a wrapper around canvas, so it will be able to write better css

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something. :)